# How to add PostgreSQL ('psql.exe') to PATH in Windows?

Tags: windows, postgresql, path

I've tried conventional way. i.e. to add it to PATH (both 'bin' and 'lib' folder) as can be seen in the 'Image 2' as below. 
I've restarted computer multiple times. Still it doesn't work.

How to add psql.exe to PATH

[image: Image 1: Here is actual PATH]

[image: Image 2: Here is command line output.]

What am I missing?

Comment: did you figure out your problem?